# Notification panel UI design issues - Expo Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am developing app using react native and expo & I have to implement push notifications in app. So far sending and receiving the notifications has no issues but my problems are mainly related to UI design on push notification panel :

Following is my simple notification message configuration :

```
scheduleNotificationAsync({
content: {
title: “You’ve got mail! :mailbox_with_mail:”,
body: ‘Here is the notification body’,
data: { data: ‘goes here’ },
},
})
```

Is there any way to design multi line notification?
I can use title, subtitle (which only works in iOS) but I want multiple lines in body part. I tried using \n in my body text but it doesn’t work.
How to navigate to specific screen in app when button is pressed in notification?
I have setup sample category as below :

```
Notifications.setNotificationCategoryAsync(“daily_question”, [
{
actionId: “yes”,
buttonTitle: “Yes”,
},
{
actionId: “no”,
buttonTitle: “No”,
},
]);
```

I would like to navigate to specific screen upon pressing of “Yes/No” button but I’m not able to figure out/able to find out, how I can write any action code in configuration.

Is there any way I can design the notification panel content UI part as html/jsx code to have better control over how UI will look like?

Is there any way to add image/table kind of components in notification ui?

It seems like adding image to push notification is under consideration.
Any pointers/guidance on achieving above points using expo notification?

If expo notification, cannot achieve above functionalities then what are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of questions but I can respond to some of them.

1. "I would like to navigate to a specific screen upon pressing of “Yes/No” button...."

   For navigating to a specific screen upon yes/no you should check this link which contains "Managing Notification Categories" and there're useful functions how to achieve that behavior. I leave the link below. If you have difficulties to find the exact way to do write here one comment, then I will leave a detailed explanation.

   https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#managing-notification-categories-interactive-notifications
2. "Is there any way I can design the notification panel content UI part as..."

   In expo managed projects it is almost impossible to design the UI of notification panel
3. "Is there any way to add image/table kind of components in notification ui"

   In Expo managed projects there is no option to add images to the notification panel, you should eject the project to do that.
4. "If expo notification, cannot achieve [...] are my options"

   You should eject the project and start to write native code which is not recommended if you are a newbie in react-native and expo.
   But if you eject to a bare project then you will have full access to your application and you can modify everything that needs native code.

Recommendation: Try to understand what you can do with managed and bare projects then you will understand what you can modify and what you can't. I leave the link below with a full explanation of the difference.

https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/